# Splitting up ember templates

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have been messing around with embejs and I have been using default index.html with script tags to render templates on the page, sufice to say my index.html file is littered with:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="aisis">
</script>
```

That I would like to split up. Now I have worked with ember a little bit in rails applications, but this app doesn't have a back end, doesn't use anything other then javascript and html as its a simple internal app.

My question is, how do I split this up into partials and various other templates and still keep the app nice and small, nice and simple? I have seen a bunch of ember tools out there that generate or scaffold projects for you, but I get lost and confused fast. Where as the way I have been doing it has taught me a lot, it's just my project is massive in one index file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember is designed so that each route should correspond against a template.  Whenever you enter a new route, a corresponding template will automatically be rendered unless you override the "renderTemplate" hook.

Try going through the "getting started" guide here: http://emberjs.com/guides/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the `yeoman` suite of tools: http://yeoman.io/

It includes an Ember generator that will scaffold your project, create your bower dependencies, generate a `grunt` file for builds, etc.  Install `generator-ember` to get started with the scaffolding.

Just create an empty folder, and from there use `yo ember` to get a complete working app.  Take a look at what is generated and you can get some ideas of what to incorporate in your app.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [Ember App Kit](http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit/). It lets you break up the templates into various files in addition to automatically importing correct modules, linting your code and providing various build options.

> Ember App Kit (EAK) is a robust starter kit for developing
>   applications in Ember.js. EAK makes it easy to develop, build, test,
>   and deploy applications independent of any back-end build process.